# Media Queries not working for email

Tags: css, responsive-design, media-queries

I've tried so many media queries to try and get this working on iPhone (landscape/portrait) and desktop but I can not seem to get it working properly on both at the same time.

Some of my classes are working but some are not.

Can someone take a look and tell me if I am using the correct queries for an email blast.
Also the class .office does not change when the viewport changes while other classes do!

http://jsfiddle.net/chrishowell/qJhu6/

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />
    <title>Sunland Group</title>
    <meta property="og:title" content="*|MC:SUBJECT|*" />
    <style type="text/css">
        @import url("http://fast.fonts.net/t/1.css?apiType=css&projectid=b075256d-62bd-45e3-843f-a9480a19a546");
        @font-face {
            font-family:"SackersGothicW01-Light";
            src:url("http://sunlandgroup.com.au/auto-response/Fonts/4a1690e1-e4c5-4644-bd72-2fdc50d48e44.eot?#iefix");
            src:url("http://sunlandgroup.com.au/auto-response/Fonts/4a1690e1-e4c5-4644-bd72-2fdc50d48e44.eot?#iefix") format("eot"), url("http://sunlandgroup.com.au/auto-response/Fonts/558e1882-61fa-42c9-b946-2ff0b251d89e.woff") format("woff"), url("Fonts/51d279cf-7422-4166-bea9-d5890c7b255a.ttf") format("truetype"), url("http://sunlandgroup.com.au/auto-response/Fonts/b3e01acf-acc5-4cc3-aef6-d05b5bf3e24a.svg#b3e01acf-acc5-4cc3-aef6-d05b5bf3e24a") format("svg");
        }
        @font-face {
            font-family:"Gill Sans W04 Book";
            src:url("http://sunlandgroup.com.au/auto-response/Fonts/c4be5717-c19c-43a5-9ad3-b548ddf070d4.eot?#iefix");
            src:url("http://sunlandgroup.com.au/auto-response/Fonts/c4be5717-c19c-43a5-9ad3-b548ddf070d4.eot?#iefix") format("eot"), url("http://sunlandgroup.com.au/auto-response/Fonts/63aa9f40-04be-453a-a672-aa8f9919115d.woff") format("woff"), url("Fonts/a82a5fb6-ad03-4675-801e-d3182a58ff5f.ttf") format("truetype"), url("http://sunlandgroup.com.au/auto-response/Fonts/beb2cee2-1a51-44ca-848f-4f795394ee5a.svg#beb2cee2-1a51-44ca-848f-4f795394ee5a") format("svg");
        }
        @font-face {
            font-family:'FontAwesome';
            src: url('http://sunlandgroup.com.au/auto-response/Fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=3.0.1');
            src: url('http://sunlandgroup.com.au/auto-response/Fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix&v=3.0.1') format('embedded-opentype'), url('http://sunlandgroup.com.au/auto-response/Fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=3.0.1') format('woff'), url('http://sunlandgroup.com.au/auto-response/Fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=3.0.1') format('truetype');
            font-weight: normal;
            font-style: normal;
        }
        /*  Font Awesome styles
------------------------------------------------------- */
        [class^="icon-"], [class*=" icon-"] {
            font-family: FontAwesome;
            font-weight: normal;
            font-style: normal;
            font-size: 10px;
            color: #a08a5e;
            text-decoration: inherit;
            -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
            /* sprites.less reset */
            display: inline;
            width: auto;
            height: auto;
            line-height: normal;
            vertical-align: baseline;
            background-image: none;
            background-position: 0% 0%;
            background-repeat: repeat;
            margin-top: 0;
        }
        .ReadMsgBody {
            width:100%;
            background-color:#ffffff;
        }
        .ExternalClass {
            width:100%;
            background-color:#ffffff;
        }
        body {
            width:100%;
            background-color:#070100;
            margin:0;
            padding:0;
            -webkit-font-smoothing:antialiased;
        }
        table {
            border-collapse: collapse;
        }
        a:link {
            color:#9b999b;
            text-decoration:none;
        }
        a:visited {
            color:#9b999b;
            text-decoration:none;
        }
        a:hover {
            color:#9b999b;
            text-decoration:none;
        }
        a:active {
            color:#9b999b;
            text-decoration:none;
        }
        .bg-black {
            background-color:#070100;
        }
        @media only screen and (max-width: 479px) {
            .office {
                font-size:8px !important
            }
            .location {
                width:5px !important
            }
            .headings {
                font-size:10px !important
            }
            .contacts {
                font-size:12px !important;
                line-height: 2 !important
            }
            .downloads {
                font-size:12px !important
            }
            .fonts-sm {
                font-size:8px !important
            }
            img {
                display:block !important
            }
            .float-l {
                float:left !important
            }
            .phone {
                font-size:22px !important;
                color: #a08a5e;
                line-height: 2 !important
            }
            .deviceWidth {
                width:100% !important;
            }
        }
        @media only screen and (max-width: 620px) {
            .office {
                font-size:10px !important;
                color: aqua !important;
            }
            body[yahoo] .downloads {
                font-size:15px !important
            }
            .fonts-sm {
                font-size:10px !important
            }
            .float-l {
                float:left !important
            }
            img {
                display:block !important
            }
            .deviceWidth {
                max-width:600px !important;
            }
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body leftmargin="0" topmargin="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" yahoo="fix" style="color:#333333; background:#ffffff; font-family:'Gill Sans W04 Book',Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;" text="#333333" ;>
    <div style="background-color:#070100;">
        <table height="100%" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="3px">
            <tr>
                <td valign="top" align="left">
                    <table class="deviceWidth" border="1px" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center" bgcolor="#070100" BORDERCOLOR="RED">
                        <tr>
                            <!------------------------------>
                            <!--! TableSide-->
                            <!------------------------------>
                            <td width="5%">
                                <img src="http://sunlandgroup.com.au/auto-response/images/images/blank-gif.gif" alt="" height="1" width="1">
                            </td>
                            <!------------------------------>
                            <!--! Table Main-->
                            <!------------------------------>
                            <td width="90%" valign="top">
                                <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center" bgcolor="#070100">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <img src="http://sunlandgroup.com.au/auto-response/images/logo.gif" width="1000" height="600" alt="" border="0" style="width:100%; height:auto; display:block">
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td style="color:#a08a5e; text-transform:uppercase; line-height:1.4; font-size:16px;text-align:center; font-family:'SackersGothicW01-Light', Helvetica, Arial, Sans-Serif;"><span class="headings">THANK YOU {!lead.FirstName} {!lead.LastName}</span>

                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td height="120">
                                            <img src="http://sunlandgroup.com.au/auto-response/images/images/blank-gif.gif" alt="" height="1" width="1">
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td align="left" valign="top">
                                            <img src="http://sunlandgroup.com.au/auto-response/images/peninsula_hero.jpg" width="1000" height="625" alt="" border="0" style="width:100%; height:auto; display:block">
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td height="120">
                                            <img src="http://sunlandgroup.com.au/auto-response/images/images/blank-gif.gif" alt="" height="1" width="1">
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td style="color:#a08a5e; font-size:16px;text-align:center; font-family:'SackersGothicW01-Light', Helvetica, Arial, Sans-Serif;"><span class="headings">FOR A PERSONAL VIEWING</span>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td height="20">
                                            <img src="http://sunlandgroup.com.au/auto-response/images/images/blank-gif.gif" alt="" height="1" width="1">
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td style="color:#f7f2ec; font-size:15px; text-align:center; font-family:'Gill Sans W04 Book',Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;"><span class="contacts">CONTACT</span>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td style="color:#f7f2ec; font-size:15px;text-align:center;font-family:'Gill Sans W04 Book',Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;"><span class="contacts">CAMERON BUCHANAN</span>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td style="color:#f7f2ec; font-size:15px;text-align:center; font-family:'Gill Sans W04 Book',Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;"><a href="tel:0414791811" style="color:#f7f2ec; text-decoration:none"><span class="phone">0414 791 811</span></a>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td style="color:#f7f2ec; font-size:15px; text-align:center; font-family:'Gill Sans W04 Book',Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;"><a href="mailto:cbuchanan@sunlandgroup.com.au" style="color:#ffffff; text-decoration:none"><span class="contacts">cbuchanan@sunlandgroup.com.au</span></a>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td height="120">
                                            <img src="http://sunlandgroup.com.au/auto-response/images/images/blank-gif.gif" alt="" height="1" width="1">
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td align="left" valign="top">
                                            <img src="http://sunlandgroup.com.au/auto-response/images/line.gif" width="1000" height="3" alt="" border="0" style="width:100%; height:auto; display:block">
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td align="left" valign="top">
                                            <img src="http://sunlandgroup.com.au/auto-response/images/peninsula.png" width="1000" height="626" alt="" border="0" style="width:100%; height:auto; display:block">
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td align="left" valign="top">
                                            <img src="http://sunlandgroup.com.au/auto-response/images/img_07.jpg" width="1000" height="623" alt="" border="0" style="width:100%; height:auto; display:block">
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <img src="http://sunlandgroup.com.au/auto-response/images/img_08.gif" width="1000" height="146" alt="" border="0" style="width:100%; height:auto; display:block">
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td style=" color:#a08a5e; text-align:center; letter-spacing: 0.1em; font-family:'SackersGothicW01-Light',Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;line-height:1.2"><span class="headings">DOWNLOADS</span>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td height="20">
                                            <img src="http://sunlandgroup.com.au/auto-response/images/images/blank-gif.gif" alt="" height="1" width="1">
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <table width="100%" border="1px solid #333">
                                        <tr>
                                            <td width="48%" align="right" style=" color:#9b999b; font-family:'Gill Sans W04 Book',Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"> <a href="#" alt="LOCATION">

                                <i class="icon-">&#xf078;</i></span>
                                <span class="downloads">LOCATION MAP</span></a>
                                            </td>
                                            <td width="4%"></td>
                                            <td width="48%" style=" color:#9b999b; font-family:'Gill Sans W04 Book',Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"> <a href="#" alt="FLOOR PLANS">

                                <i class="icon-">&#xf078;</i></span>
                                <span class="downloads">FLOOR PLANS</span></a>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td width="48%" align="right" style=" color:#9b999b; font-family:'Gill Sans W04 Book',Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;letter-spacing:1px"> <a href="#" alt="MASTER PLAN">

                                <i class="icon-">&#xf078;</i></span>
                                <span class="downloads">MASTER PLAN</span></a>
                                            </td>
                                            <td width="4%"></td>
                                            <td width="48%" style=" color:#9b999b; font-family:'Gill Sans W04 Book',Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;letter-spacing:1px"> <a href="#" alt="FACT SHEET">

                                <span class="downloads">
                                <i class="icon-">&#xf078;</i></span>
                                <span class="downloads">FACT SHEET</span></a>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table>
                                    <table width="90%" border="1" BORDERCOLOR="#333" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center" bgcolor="#070100">
                                        <tr>
                                            <td height="60">
                                                <img src="http://sunlandgroup.com.au/auto-response/images/images/blank-gif.gif" alt="" height="1" width="1">
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td style="font-size:10px; color:#ffffff; text-align:center; font-family:'Gill Sans W04 Book',Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;"><span class="office">NATIONAL OFFICE: ROYAL PINES RESORT, MARINA VILLAGE ROSS STREET BENOWA QUEENSLAND 4217  PHONE:<a href="tel: +61 7 5564 3700" style="color:#ffffff; text-decoration:none"> +61 7 5564 3700 </a><a href="http://www.sunlandgroup.com.au/" target="_blank" style="color:#ffffff; text-decoration:none" >SUNLANDGROUP.COM.AU</a></span>

                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td height="30">
                                                <img src="http://sunlandgroup.com.au/auto-response/images/images/blank-gif.gif" alt="" height="1" width="1">
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td style="font-size:10px; text-align:center;color:#9b999b; font-family:'Gill Sans W04 Book',Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; letter-spacing:1px;"><span class="office">COPYRIGHT 2013 SUNLAND GROUP  LIMITED ALL RIGHTS RESERVED.  DISCLAIMER  PRIVACY POLICY</span>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td height="30">
                                                <img src="http://sunlandgroup.com.au/auto-response/images/images/blank-gif.gif" alt="" height="1" width="1">
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <!------------------------------>
                                        <!--! TableSide-->
                                        <!------------------------------>
                                        <td width="5%">
                                            <img src="http://sunlandgroup.com.au/auto-response/images/images/blank-gif.gif" alt="" height="1" width="1">
                                        </td>
                        </tr>
                        </table>
                        </td>
                        <td width="50">
                            <img src="http://sunlandgroup.com.au/auto-response/images/images/blank-gif.gif" alt="" height="1" width="1">
                        </td>
            </tr>
            </table>
            </table>
</body>
```

Comment: Looks fine on Chrome in OS X 10.9. Try setting "all and ()" instead of "only screen ()" on the queries.

Answer (score 2):

Change the media query from

```
 @media only screen and (max-width: 479px) {
```

to

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {
```

Also the reason the font size you've set doesn't change when the viewport changes is because it is smaller than what the iPhone email client deems to be its smallest user readable size, so it adjusts it up. A way to force the client to render the font size you've selected is to add `-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;` inside your `.office` rule.

Responsive email design can be very hard to figure out with all the differnt email clients out there. A good primer is this guide: http://www.campaignmonitor.com/guides/mobile/

Comment: I am curious why this was downvoted. Its a common practice to use max-device-width to target mobile devices on email.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I can guess that the downvote comes because this isn't really an answer. It is a question and a suggestion and should normally come as a comment. With your reputation of "1", however you can't comment, so you are kinda stuck. Try to get some more reputation by valid means before leaving this kind of non-answer.

Comment: Thanks David. I felt that it was at least partially an answer as the way the media query was structured could have been a culprit. Oh well.

Answer (score 0):

I once had a problem in Yahoo! Mail when using `.fonts-sm` . In stead I used `td[class="fonts-sm"]` in stead. Try applying styles in your media queries using this technique.

Comment: It's just weird that some of my classes are working and other are not

Comment: I just tested in my chrome browsers and it works as expected. Have you tried @Sam Pettersson's suggestion?

Comment: Have u tested with Email On Acid or Litmus?